# How busy are the Faroe Islands during summer compared to Iceland?

Tags: iceland, summer, faroe-islands, greenland

Having been to Iceland a few times, I know how extremely busy it can get in the summer, especially in the south. Last summer I was in Greenland and I really enjoyed the absence of mass tourism.

How do the Faroe Islands compare to this for the months of July and August?

Comment: I was there in late August and it did not feel crowded at all. Camping grounds or restaurants had ample space. Just a single anecdote though, so I'm posting as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: If you go to Iceland and find crowds, go elsewhere :) For example, I promise you will never find crowds at [Þjórsárver](https://www.ni.is/is/midlun/natturuminjaskra/thjorsarver).  In my experience, the solitude you can find in Iceland any time of year is unmatched even by Sweden, Norway, or Russia.  Of course, if you look for them, crowded places exist in all countries.

Answer (score 7):

In 2017 [2.1 million](https://www.cntraveler.com/gallery/reasons-to-visit-the-faroe-islands) people visited Iceland. In the same year an estimate of [224,000](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/news/2017/06/12/faroe-islands-airport-travel/) people visited the Faroe Islands, so all together the islands get significantly fewer visitors, which would indicate that many fewer tourists will be around even in the summer months.

In June 2016 Iceland had [221,900](https://www.ferdamalastofa.is/static/files/ferdamalastofa/Frettamyndir/2018/oktober/tourism-in-iceland-2018.pdf), where as Faroe had only [22,570](https://visitfaroeislands.com/content/uploads/2017/06/visitfaroeislandsannualreport2016en.pdf). (June was the only month I could find for both sources, apologies) Hope this helps!

Edit: To provide context from someone who has been, I've spoken to my uncle who has lived in Iceland during 2016/17. He said that he wasn't around during those summer months, but Iceland was always pretty busy with tourists & was easy to feel crowded. The Islands were far more calm, but tourist spots such as Puffin watching or old ruins are still busy as that's what people come for (and why he went)

Comment: That's the plain numbers. However, Faroe islands cover an area of 1395 sqaure km, but iceland with 103128 square km is a lot bigger. So while the tourist numbers are only one tenth, The size is actually one hundredth. Someone who has actually been there should tell if this feels "crowded" or not.

Comment: @Sebastian Will update with some comments from those who have been